# Why does $\sqrt[n]{n} = e^{\frac{\log n}{n}}$?

Tags: analysis

$\sqrt[n]{n} = e^{\frac{\log n}{n}}$

I came upon this equation on this site but with no further explanation and frankly I don't understand how can we get $e^{\frac{\log n}{n}}$ from $\sqrt[n]{n}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $n=e^{\log n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}=(e^{\ln x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Now we know,  $e^{\ln x}=x$.
So  $e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}=(e^{\ln x})^{\frac{1}{x}}=\sqrt[x]x$
□

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple application of the logarithm and exponential operators. In fact in general, when $f(x)>0$ you have

$$f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\ln f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}\tag 1$$
Hence, in your case,

$$\sqrt[n]{n} \equiv n^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac 1n \ln n}=e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's clear to me now.

Comment: @badatmath You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Writing $n$ as in the other form, namely $n=e^{\ln (n)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I see it now and I feel so stupid now, so trivial.